# Swift: Does not have a member named

Tags: uitableview, swift

I am trying to figure out how Swift works. and right now I'm working on a table view cell, but there seems to be a problem.

```
import UIKit

class ProfileTableViewCell : UITableViewCell{
    @IBOutlet var profilePicImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var profileNameText: UILabel!

}
```

ove

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cellResult :Dictionary<CellType, Dictionary<String, String>>  = menuList[indexPath.row]

        var cellType: CellType = Array(cellResult.keys)[0]
        var cellData: Dictionary<String, String> = cellResult[cellType] as Dictionary<String, String>!

        if(cellType == CellType.Profile){
            var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("DisplayPicCellIdentifier") as? ProfileTableViewCell
            if (cell == nil) {
                cell = ProfileTableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "DisplayPicCellIdentifier")
            }
            cell.profileNameText!.text! = cellData["displayName"] // Error 'ProfileTableViewCell? does not have member named 'profileNameText'
           // cell.setProfileNameText(cellData["displayName"])
            return cell!
        }
```

I keep getting this error does not have member named in profileNameText, may I ask how I am able to fix such issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the line to

```
cell!.profileNameText.text = cellData["displayName"]
```